# Stuck on the login screen

Tags: boot, grub2

I have been trying to run Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

For some reason I cannot get past the password screen and I have tried many different things that I don't understand.

I tried entering GNU GRUB and did some things. I entered the BIOS and tried things and to make sure, did them 10 more times.

I am a total beginner so I expected to run into many troubles along the way but didn't expect not to be able to start the OS.

Comment: Probably your GUI / GDM is broken is this a fresh install ?

Comment: Edit your question to show us the complete output of `apt list ubuntu-desktop` and of `apt list openssh-server`